# Changing reading speed from book to chapter in Kindle

Tags: kindle, time-to-read

How do I change the reading speed bar from displaying "Mins left in book" to "Mins left in chapter"?

Device:  Kindle - 6" Glare-Free Touchscreen Display, Wi-Fi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tap in the lower left corner on the reading speed indicator.

Comment: Thank You. Worked.  Didn't know it's that easy :D